# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null

Tags: java, image

i used this code to convert an array of bits to bufferedimage but its giving an error

```
 ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);      
  BufferedImage finale=new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

  finale=ImageIO.read(bais);
  File outputfile = new File("C:\\Users\\Divya Prakash\\Desktop\\image32.jpg");
  ImageIO.write(finale, "jpg", outputfile);
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1592)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
    at imgpros.Imgpros.main(Imgpros.java:113)
Java Result: 1
```

how can i remove the error?

Comment: Evidently your image is becoming null at some point. Debug to find out why.

Comment: Also, your second line doesn't do anything since you immediately overwrite the reference with `read`.

Comment: Looks like no registered `ImageReader` is able to read your `bais`-stream.

Answer (score 2):

As one comment shows, ImageIO probably isnt able to read a `ByteInputStream`. Or, probably, your array cant be converted to a `ByteInputStream`. So this returns null. Try :

```
System.out.println(bais==null);
```

If this prints `true`, you can :

- a) look for another way to convert your array into a `BufferedImage`

  For this, I would suggest to define width and height for your `BufferedImage` :

  ```
  finale=new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
  ```

  Then, fill it with the points from your array :

  ```
  for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; x=x+1) {
      for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; y=y+1) {
          finale.setRGB(x,y,arr[y*w+x]);
      }
  }
  ```

  If its an int array...
- b) Check if ImageIO can handle your `ByteInputStream`.

  - Try this : `InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);`

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Not sure what the root cause is. Resolved after the image was edited using Paint.